# How to execute .net console exe( eg. MyTool.exe) from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How to execute .net console exe( eg. MyTool.exe) from PowerShell.

Well my requirement is to execute this console application from Powershell.

Which in turn wants to execute this powershell script from windows schedular.

Thanks
Siraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell is a shell.  To start an executable, you simply enter the name of the executable, with the path if needed.

For example, all these commands will run the `hostname` command on a default install of Windows:

```
HOSTNAME
hostname.exe
C:\Windows\System32\HOSTNAME.EXE
& "C:\Windows\System32\HOSTNAME.EXE"
```

The last example makes use of the call operator (See `Get-Help about_Operators`).  That's necessary if you wish to call an executable that has a space in the file name or path name.

If you wish to schedule a console application with Task Scheduler, however, you don't need to call it from PowerShell.  If you insist that you must, however, you can use the command line switches for PowerShell.exe and call it with a command line.  See `PowerShell.exe -?`.